# Consistent spacing between labels c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to align an amount of labels with consistent spacing. The alignment after the for loop is fine, but why is it that the first spacing in inconsistent with the others ?

```
   private void FrmMainGame_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label l = new Label();
        int margin = 1;
        int width = (this.ClientSize.Width + margin - l.Size.Width) /10 ;
        l.BackColor = Color.Red;
        l.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        int x = width + margin;
        l.Location = new Point(0, 5);
        l.Size = new Size(width, 20);
        this.Controls.Add(l);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            l = new Label();
            l.BackColor = Color.Red;
            l.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            x += margin + width;
            l.Location = new Point(x,5);
            l.Size = new Size(width, 20);
            this.Controls.Add(l);
        }
    }
```

[Image of executed code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Pm3V.png)

Comment: Is this winforms?  WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at these lines:

`int x = width + margin;
l.Location = new Point(0, 5);`

In your loop, each button is placed at:

`l.Location = new Point(x, 5);`

Seems like you just typed `0` where you meant to put `x`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're setting int `x= width + margin` before the loop. If width=10, then you're setting x to 11 (right after the first label). Then, in the loop, before placing the second label, you're increasing x again to 22, before even placing the second label.

Change it to `int x=0` and I think you should be good.

Comment: Thanks ! Solved it immediately

Answer (score 0):

This is because in the loop you set the location of the new label after adding width to x.

If you suppose width = 10, before the loop starts x = 11 then you set x += margin + width which will make it 22. So your second label will be placed at x=22

The next iteration will be fine, but you will see the gap between the first and second label.

Try setting x = 0 before the loop starts.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the mistakes made is in de following line:

```
'int width = (this.ClientSize.Width + margin - l.Size.Width) /10 ;'
```

You take the whole length - the size of one element and divide it by 10. This actually results in width being ClienSize.Width / 11
I think one of the following is more correct, and might solve your problem:

```
 'int width = (this.ClientSize.Width + margin - l.Size.Width) /9 ;'
 'int width = (this.ClientSize.Width / 10) - (margin*2) ;'
```